# Changing content_main.xml onNavigationItemSelected

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to use multiple `content_main.xml` to change the `MainActivity` `onNavigationItemSelected` or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think you need to be a lot more specific with what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

the right way to It would be using multiple fragments in the main activity
GO to android studio and create a new project select the navigation drawer template you will get an example code now create fragments and add them on the navigation menu `onNavigationItemSelected` event.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is to have different layouts for your items in 
NavigationDrawer. Better consider using Fragments.

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_list) {
        ListFragment fragment = new ListFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        GalleryFragment fragment = new GalleryFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    return true;
}
```

this would help you to navigate to different fragment in your NavigationItem. 
Hope it helps.